# Необходимо добавить возможность добавлять OR в SQL запрос

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток!
Нужна ваша помощь.
Есть класс, который упрощает работу с базой данных.

```
<?

class DB extends MySQLi {

    public function __construct() {

        global $database;

        !empty($database['settings']['host'])       ? $this->host       = $database['settings']['host']         : $this->host = 'localhost';
        !empty($database['settings']['username'])   ? $this->username   = $database['settings']['username']     : $this->username = 'root';
        !empty($database['settings']['password'])   ? $this->password   = $database['settings']['password']     : $this->password = null;
        !empty($database['settings']['name'])       ? $this->name       = $database['settings']['name']         : $this->name = 'unknown';
        !empty($database['settings']['port'])       ? $this->port       = $database['settings']['port']         : $this->port = '3306';
        !empty($database['settings']['socket'])     ? $this->socket     = $database['settings']['socket']       : $this->socket = false;

        !empty($database['settings']['charset'])    ? $this->charset    = $database['settings']['charset']      : $this->charset = 'UTF-8';
        $database['settings']['persistent'] == 1    ? $this->persistent = 'p:'                                  : $this->persistent = null;

        $this->connection = $this->connect($this->persistent.$this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->name, $this->port, $this->socket);
        $this->set_charset($this->charset);

        if($this->connect_errno) {

            die('Не могу подключится к серверу MySQL ('.$this->connect_errno.')');

        }

    }

    private function filter($value) {

        if(!is_int($value)) {

            $value = strip_tags($value);
            $value = $this->real_escape_string($value);

        } else {

            $value = intval($value);

        }

        return $value;

        unset($value);

    }

    private function foreachToString($array = array(), $type) {

        switch($type) {

            case 'v': /* values */

                foreach($array as $key => $value) {

                    $value = $this->filter($value);

                    $values[] = '`'.$value.'`';

                }

                $name = implode(', ', $values);

            break;

            case 'fv': /* fields and values */

                foreach($array as $field => $value) {

                    $field = $this->filter($field);
                    $value = $this->filter($value);

                    $fields[] = $field;
                    $values[] = $value;

                    $name[] = '`'.$field.'` = "'.$value.'"';

                }

                $name = implode(', ', $name);

            break;

            case 'fvw': /* fields and values for WHERE */

                foreach($array as $field => $value) {

                    $field = $this->filter($field);
                    $value = $this->filter($value);

                    $fields[] = $field;
                    $values[] = $value;

                    $name[] = '`'.$field.'` = "'.$value.'"';

                }

                $name = implode(' AND ', $name);

            break;

            case 'fvwOR': /* fields and values for WHERE */

                foreach($array as $field => $value) {

                    $field = $this->filter($field);
                    $value = $this->filter($value);

                    $fields[] = $field;
                    $values[] = $value;

                    $name[] = '(`'.$field.'` = "'.$value.'")';

                }

                $name = implode(' OR ', $name);

            break;

            default:

                return false;

            break;

        }

        return $name;

        unset($array, $type, $fields, $values, $name);

    }

    /** 
    * Multipl_count
    *
    * Example usage:
    * 
    * $tables = array('users' => 'Users', 'offline' => 'Offline');
    *
    * $where = array('users' => array('login' => 'racer_official')); ** optional
    *
    * $db->multipl_count($tables, $where);
    *
    **/

    public function multiple_count($vars_tables = array(), $vars_where = array()) {

        if(!empty($vars_tables)) {

            foreach($vars_tables as $table => $value) {

                $table = $this->filter($table);
                $value = $this->filter($value);

                $tables[] = $table;
                $as[] = $value;

                if(!empty($vars_where[$table])) {

                    $where = $this->foreachToString($vars_where[$table], 'fvw');
                    $where = ' WHERE '.$where;

                } else {

                    $where  = false;

                }

                $name[] = '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `'.$table.'`'.$where.') as '.$value;

            }

            $name = implode(', ', $name);

            $sql = 'SELECT '.$name;
            $result = $this->query($sql);

            return $sql;

            $result->close();

        }

        unset($table, $vars_columns, $columns, $vars_where, $where, $fetch, $sql, $result, $data);

    }


}

?>
```

Есть запрос вида:

```
$db = new DB();

$tables = array($database['tables']['users'] => 'validUser', $database['tables']['bans'] => 'checkBan');
$where = array(

    $database['tables']['users'] => array(

        'OR' => array(

            'login' => $login,
            'mail' => $login

        )

    ),

    $database['tables']['bans'] => array(

        'type' => 'Auth',
        'OR' => array(

            'login' => $login,
            'mail' => $login

        )

    )

);

var_dump($db->multiple_count($tables, $where));
```

Нужно получить sql следующего вида:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`
WHERE `e-mail` = 'test' OR `login` = 'test') AS validUser,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `bans` 
WHERE `type` = 'Auth' AND (`e-mail` = 'test' OR `login` = 'test')) AS checkBan
```

Comment: @E_p послушайте, я ведь не прошу советов по тому, как использовать. Я спросил конкретно, как мне реализовать то, что мне необходимо. Вы разводите тут чат какой-то. Знаете, как помочь по конкретному вопросу - помогите.
Расширение класса, как раз таки создает мобильность. Исправив в одном месте, мне не нужно будет править 100500 файлов, чтобы просто добавить проверку, которая возможно понадобится в будущем. Один раз напишу класс и затем буду пользоваться им во всех своих проектах. Добра.

Comment: Действуйте строго по шагам. 1) выкидываете ваш класс. 2) Берёте что-то наподобие [FluentPDO](https://github.com/envms/fluentpdo) 3) Profit. Поверьте мне лично как разработчика велосипеда своего класса БД.

Comment: @ArchDemon действуй строго по шагам: 1) закрываешь страницу браузера. 2) Идешь читать, что-то наподобие: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.inheritance.php
Поверьте, мне лично все равно, что вы думаете. Я считаю наследование класса - хорошей вещью, а то что я пишу только нужный мне функционал своим кодом без миллиона строк не нужного мне - это моя проблема.

Comment: Вы на публичном ресурсе задали вопрос. Выставили на паказ код очень низкого качества(за такое на код ревью стреляют). На халяву получили советов от людей у которых есть опыт. Если вам советы не нужны то хамить не нужно. А потом с гордостью выставили вариант который не сможет сделать `(a = "b" or c="d") and (e="f" or g="h")`. Зачем? Сидите дома и варитесь в своём соку.

Comment: @E_p я никому не хамил. Я представил кусок кода, то что нужно для того, чтобы помочь мне с вопросом. Данный веб-ресурс и создан для бесплатной помощи. Ну и напоследок - сейчас у меня нет необходимости в том,  что вы написали, для этого есть другая функция.

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил сам. Изменения здесь:

```
private function foreachToString($array = array(), $type) {

        switch($type) {

            case 'v': /* values */

                foreach($array as $key => $value) {

                    $value = $this->filter($value);

                    $values[] = '`'.$value.'`';

                }

                $name = implode(', ', $values);

            break;

            case 'fv': /* fields and values */

                foreach($array as $field => $value) {

                    $field = $this->filter($field);
                    $value = $this->filter($value);

                    $fields[] = $field;
                    $values[] = $value;

                    $name[] = '`'.$field.'` = "'.$value.'"';

                }

                $name = implode(', ', $name);

            break;

            case 'fvwAND': /* fields and values for WHERE */

                foreach($array as $field => $value) {

                    $field = $this->filter($field);
                    $value = $this->filter($value);

                    $fields[] = $field;
                    $values[] = $value;

                    $name[] = '`'.$field.'` = "'.$value.'"';

                }

                $name = implode(' AND ', $name);

            break;

            case 'fvwOR': /* fields and values for WHERE */

                foreach($array as $field => $value) {

                    $field = $this->filter($field);
                    $value = $this->filter($value);

                    $fields[] = $field;
                    $values[] = $value;

                    $name[] = '`'.$field.'` = "'.$value.'"';

                }

                $name = '('.implode(' OR ', $name).')';

            break;

            default:

                return false;

            break;

        }

        return $name;

        unset($array, $type, $fields, $values, $name);

    }
```

И здесь:

```
public function multiple_count($vars_tables = array(), $vars_where = array()) {

        if(!empty($vars_tables)) {

            foreach($vars_tables as $table => $value) {

                $table = $this->filter($table);
                $value = $this->filter($value);

                $tables[] = $table;
                $as[] = $value;

                if(!empty($vars_where[$table])) {

                    if(array_key_exists('OR', $vars_where[$table])) {

                        $where = $this->foreachToString($vars_where[$table]['OR'], 'fvwOR');
                        unset($vars_where[$table]['OR']);
                        $where .= ' AND ';
                    }

                    $where .= $this->foreachToString($vars_where[$table], 'fvwAND');
                    $where = ' WHERE '.$where;

                } else {

                    $where  = false;

                }

                $name[] = '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `'.$table.'`'.$where.') as '.$value;

            }

            $name = implode(', ', $name);

            $sql = 'SELECT '.$name;
            $result = $this->query($sql);

            return $sql;

            $result->close();

        }

        unset($table, $vars_columns, $columns, $vars_where, $where, $fetch, $sql, $result, $data);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я полностью согласен что **ваш класс лучше не использовать**.

Если вам это интересно для практики то вот решение проблемы.

```php
<?php

function buildWhere($where, $w = 'AND') {
    if (is_string($where)) {
        return $where;
    }

    if (!is_array($where)) {
        return '';
    }

    $whereVals = [];
    foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $j = strtolower($key) === 'or' ? 'OR' : 'AND';
            $whereVals[] = sprintf('(%s)', buildWhere($value, $j));
        } else {
            $whereVals[] = sprintf('%s = "%s"', $key, $value);
        }

    }

    return implode(" $w ", $whereVals);
}

$where = [
    "a"  => "b",
    // Joins with "or"
    "or" => [
        "c" => "d",
        "e" => "f"
    ],
    // Joins with "and"
    "meh" => [
        "aa" => "bb",
        "cc" => "dd"
    ]
];

var_dump(buildWhere($where));
// string(62) "a = "b" AND (c = "d" OR e = "f") AND (aa = "bb" AND cc = "dd")"

$where = [
    [
        "or" => [
            "a" => "b",
            "c" => "d"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "or" => [
            "aa" => "bb",
            "cc" => "dd"
        ]
    ]
];

var_dump(buildWhere($where));
// string(53) "((a = "b" OR c = "d")) AND ((aa = "bb" OR cc = "dd"))"
```